# How to create a mock observable to test http rxjs retry/retryWhen in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I have a http request of this form in my angular app: `this.http.get(url,options).pipe(retry(5))`

I want to unit test this using jasmine, such that the http request first returns an error but on a subsequent try, returns the expected data.

I previously returned http errors in this format as recommended by the angular.io documentation `spyOn(http,'get').and.returnValue(defer(() => Promise.reject(errorObject)));`

The rxjs operator retry does not seem to call the http.get function again, so changing the return value of the spy does not work. What I think I need to do is somehow return an observable from the spy which first emits the error and later emits the data. I thought about using a BehaviorSubject but don't think that accepts errors to be passed.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

If we go to angular [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/common/http/src/client.ts) we will see next:

```
// Start with an Observable.of() the initial request, and run the handler (which
// includes all interceptors) inside a concatMap(). This way, the handler runs
// inside an Observable chain, which causes interceptors to be re-run on every
// subscription (this also makes retries re-run the handler, including interceptors).
const events$: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> =
    of (req).pipe(concatMap((req: HttpRequest<any>) => this.handler.handle(req)));
```

To make request retriable they are starting it with of(req), so we could do the same to emulate this behavior in unit tests. For example:

```
spyOn(http,"get").and.returnValue(
    createRetriableStream(
       throwError("err"),
       throwError("err"),
       throwError("err"),
       of("a")
    )
);
```

Where createRetriableStream function could look like it:

```
function createRetriableStream(...resp$: any): any {
   let fetchData: Spy = createSpy("fetchData");
   fetchData.and.returnValues(...resp$);
   return of(undefined).pipe(switchMap((_) => fetchData()));
}
```

Usually, retry logic is used together with a delay between attempt, to cover this part you could use [time progression syntax](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/marble-testing.md#time-progression-syntax). So your tests could look like:

```
    it("throw error after 2 retries", () => {
        testScheduler.run(({ cold, expectObservable }) => {
            source$ = createRetriableStream(cold("-#"), cold("-#"), cold("-#"),cold("-3")).pipe(
                retryWhen(
                   return errors.pipe(
                       mergeMap((err) => {                
                           return 2 > repeatCount
                               ? throwError(err)
                               : timer(100, testScheduler);             
                       })
                  );)
             );
        expectObservable(source$).toBe("- 200ms --#");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed effective.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below method. Also can you post whole code for the function?

```
it('should check for the get error call ', () => {
            spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));
            fixture.detectChanges() // or component.function()
            expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm already able to throw an error using the above code spyOn(http,'get').and.returnValue(defer(() => Promise.reject(errorObject))); What I want to do is throw an error on the first try but on the retry using rxjs, it should get the actual data

Comment: Sounds good please answer your own question so it would be helpful for others

Comment: Thanks but you might be misunderstanding my question? I'm concerned with testing the retry of the http call, not the first call

Comment: oh yeah I am sorry